# Function to substitute a constructor with another constructor

Tags: haskell, constructor

I'm trying to write a function which gets an expression, and substitutes a specific constructor with another one, within the given expression.
Something similar to this:

**Input**: f X Y
**Output**:f X Z
Both Y and Z belong to the same datatype and moreover they derive from show, so I can compare constructors. My problem is I don't know how to replace one constructor within an expression. Is it actually possible?

[Edit]: some snippet to clarify my question:

```
data Message = X | Y | Z deriving(show)
data Term = F Message Message | G Term

substitute::Term->Term
substitue Term = -- another term with Y replaced with Z
```

Comment: Please provide a short runnable (sans the definition of the required function) example, indicating expected results. Is ``f`` the function you want to write, or is it some other function that operates on ``f X Y``? What is ``X``?

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of a feature from another language that you would like to emulate in Haskell? If so then its generally a clue that you need to learn to think in Haskell instead.

Comment: This sounds like you want Template Haskell, but it's hard to tell from your question.

Comment: Are you looking for pattern matching?

Comment: Maybe 4 next lines: `substitueY2Z (F Y Y)= F Z Z `  then `substitueY2Z (F a Y)= F a Z` and `substitueY2Z (F Y b)= F Z b`, finally `substitueY2Z t = t`

Comment: Consider `data Term a = F a a | G (Term a); instance Functor Term where { fmap f (F a b) = F (f a) (f b); fmap f (G t) = G (fmap f t) }; subs Y = Z; subs m = m` and then your function is `fmap subs :: Term Message -> Term Message`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you are talking about pattern matching:

```
data Message = X | Y | Z deriving (Show)
data Term = F Message Message deriving (Show)

substitute :: Term -> Term
substitute (F Y x) = substitute (F Z x)
substitute (F x Y) = F x Z
substitute t = t


main = do
    print $ substitute $ F X X
    print $ substitute $ F X Y
    print $ substitute $ F Y X
    print $ substitute $ F Y Y
```

Outputs:

```
F X X
F X Z
F Z X
F Z Z
```

Comment: No , actually this was only a simple example. the input expression can be too long and complicated,making it impossible to predict every possible pattern.

Comment: First, you do not need all possible patterns --- only those with replaceable terms in them, which means that the number of pattern matching statements is equal to the number of constructor arguments. And if you have more than several arguments in your constructor, you probably need to refactor your types.

Comment: You can also divide this into two problems, one which modifies messages ans one which performs the substitution in the Term. The lazy Haskell programer's way to map a function over Terms would be to define `data TermF a = F a a | G (TermF a) deriving (Functor)` and `type Term = TermF Message`. Then you can to something like `yToZ Y = Z` and `yToZ a = a`.  Then `fmap yToZ` would be the same as `substitute`. Unless there's some other complexity not described in the question, this is already the answer.

Comment: If the OP wants to be able to create the functions that replace the constructors from data, then they're looking for a function `replace :: Message -> Message -> Message -> Message`. This is easily accomplished by making `Message` `Eq` by `data Message = X | Y | Z deriving (Eq, Show)`. Then we can define `replace :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> a -> a` as `replace find replacement x = case x == find of True -> replacement, _ -> x`. Then `fmap (replace Y Z)` would be the same as `substitute`.